# What does the OProfile warning 'dropping hyperspace sample' mean?

Tags: c, linux, profiling, performance-testing, oprofile

When using the statistical execution profiler OProfile to visualise a callgraph profile for my C application, it includes the following warning multiple times. The warning is rather cryptic to me:

```
warning: dropping hyperspace sample at offset 1af9 >= 2be8 for binary /home/myuser/mybinary
```

I'm using OProfile in a Xen virtualized environment like this:

```
modprobe oprofile timer=1
opcontrol --no-vmlinux
opcontrol --start
(wait for profiling data to accumulate)
opcontrol --stop
opreport --session-dir=/var/lib/oprofile --exclude-dependent --demangle=smart \
--symbols /home/myuser/mybinary --callgraph
```

The complete output from the last command is:

```
Overflow stats not available
CPU: CPU with timer interrupt, speed 0 MHz (estimated)
Profiling through timer interrupt
warning: dropping hyperspace sample at offset 84d0 >= 79a0 for binary /home/myuser/mybinary
warning: dropping hyperspace sample at offset 7ac0 >= 79a0 for binary /home/myuser/mybinary
warning: dropping hyperspace sample at offset 7d90 >= 79a0 for binary /home/myuser/mybinary
warning: dropping hyperspace sample at offset 7ac0 >= 79a0 for binary /home/myuser/mybinary
warning: dropping hyperspace sample at offset 7d90 >= 79a0 for binary /home/myuser/mybinary
warning: dropping hyperspace sample at offset 8210 >= 79a0 for binary /home/myuser/mybinary
samples  %        symbol name
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

After that it prints plausible-looking call graph data.

What does the 'hyperspace' warning mean? What causes it? Does it impact profiling results? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maynard Johnson explains this warning in [a message to a mailinglist](http://old.nabble.com/hyperspace-sample-question-td27940389.html):

> There have been cases reported where samples recorded by the oprofile
>   kernel driver appear to be attributed to the wrong binary, in
>   particular if the sample rate is very high or when doing callgraph
>   profiling (since callgraph profiling, like a high sample rate, also
>   results in very high overhead of the oprofile kernel driver and
>   overflows of its internal sample buffers).  I suspect that's what
>   you're running into.  Unfortunately, this is a very insidious bug, and
>   no one has been able to find the root cause yet.  The kernel driver
>   does report overflow counts of its internal buffers, and the oprofiled
>   log prints those out.  As a convenience, starting with oprofile 0.9.5,
>   opreport will also print a warning when it finds non-zero overflow
>   counts and suggests lowering the sampling interval.
>
> I suggest looking in your /var/lib/oprofile/samples/oprofiled.log and
>   find the overflow statistics for the above profile run (log entries
>   are timestamped).  If you're only seeing a few or a very small
>   percentage (say, less than 3%), you can probably just ignore the
>   anomalies.  In general, to avoid/limit this kind of thing, you should
>   profile at the lowest sampling rate practical, especially when you're
>   doing callgraph profiling.  So what do I mean by "practical"?  Well,
>   as with any sample-based profiler, oprofile is statistical in nature. 
>   And the more data points you have, the more confidence you have in the
>   data.  So for 100% confidence, you should (theoretically) profile with
>   a count value of '1'.  Not too practical, though, since your machine
>   may appear to lock up because most of the work being done is recording
>   samples.  For cycles event profiling, you can probably use a count
>   value of several million or so (on today's processors) and still be
>   pretty confident of the da  ta.  For other events, it really depends
>   on their frequency of occurrence.